# upgraded sklearn makes my previous onehotencoder failed to tranform

Tags: scikit-learn

I stored one of my previous ml model into pickle and plan to use it later for production.

Everything works fine for quite a while. Months later, I upgraded my sklearn, now i load it i got this warning...

```
> c:\programdata\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:318:
> UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator OneHotEncoder from version
> 0.20.1 when using version 0.22.2.post1. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.   UserWarning)
```

When i used it for transform, i got this error:

```
model_pipeline["ohe"].transform(df)
```

Error says:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-72436472fbb4> in <module>
----> 1 model_pipeline["ohe"].transform(df_merge[['CATEGORY']][:])

c:\programdata\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_encoders.py in transform(self, X)
    392         n_samples, n_features = X_int.shape
    393 
--> 394         if self.drop is not None:
    395             to_drop = self.drop_idx_.reshape(1, -1)
    396 

AttributeError: 'OneHotEncoder' object has no attribute 'drop'
```

This is model pipeline is trained very expensively. Is there any for me to fix this model pipeline without retraining everything? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've also encountered the same problem. In my case it was because of trying to load and use encoder I've created with a prior version of scikit-learn. When I re-created the encoder and saved, problem after loading disappeared.